# Installed custom Android 5 ROM, but how to upgrade now or return to official one?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I bought Galaxy S5 from T-Mobile which had Android 4.4 (last year). Back in October I needed Android 5 to test a mobile application (I am a developer) and I installed official S5 Polish ROM which was the only one available in December last year.

Now, I don't need it any more as it does not work perfectly well (but had to stick to it till now).

How can I return my original ROM?

Comment: If you included the bootloader while updating then you unfortunately can't downgrade anymore.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab If I find the official ROM of my provider and install it via Odin, will I be able to receive updates then?

Comment: Only if it from your country. Otherwise OTA updates won't work

Comment: @SuperThomasLab Yes, it from my country. So that is how it works. I thought the provider matters not country. Thanks